# Parallelize inner loop in Julia

Tags: julia

I have been trying to learn how to perform distributed parallel programming in Julia and would like to clarify some doubts.

```
using Distributed

addprocs(4)

@everywhere function foo(n)
    sleep(0.001)
    return randn(10)
end

function inner_loop(func, n_times)
    out = @distributed (+) for var = [10 for i=1:n_times]
        func(var);
    end
end

function main(n_outer_loops)
    out=zeros(10);
    for i=1:n_outer_loops
        out += inner_loop(foo, 10)
    end
    return out;
end

r = main(4)
```

My inner loop is running in parallel with the `@distributed` macro and with the `reduction` `(+)`. Does the function wait until each `func` is complete in each processor and then adds it to the solution?
For `var=1`, `Worker1` completes `func`,…`WorkerN` completes `func`. Afterward, add everything to `out`.

Or does it add to the solution as soon as `func` is complete in a worker? `Worker1` completes `func`, adds to `out`,… `WorkerN` completes `func` adds to `out`.

Since this is parallelizing only the inner loop, is this a suitable implementation? Or is Julia creating and destroying the parallel portion at each `outer_loop` and thus having a non-trivial overhead? If so, can it be created once, and then assign the jobs in the inner_loops?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the two `out` are different local variables, that you happened to name the same, but are not related.

The inner loop returns automatically the latest value, that you named `out` like the name in the outer loop..

So, the computation of each "inner out" is parallelised, and when each process has done, its value is added to the "outer out" and a new parallel computation is started.

Comment: Is this efficient within julia? Opening and closing the parallel communications at each step in the loop?

Comment: I am not a parallel expert, but I believe the "opening of the communication" happens only once, with `addprocs`. Also, consider threads instead of processes, they sre cheapper and Julia now offres a mature thread API..

Answer (score 0):

`@distributed` is adding a communication overhead whic is significant for jobs having running times below a millisecond. Consider the following code (I assume `addprocs(4)`):

```
function job(K)
    @distributed (+) for i in 1:K
        rand()
    end
end
```

Let us use it to calculate a sum of 120 numbers:

```
julia> @btime sum(job(12) for j in 1:10)
  1.946 ms (2661 allocations: 127.89 KiB)
58.81040365866255

julia> @btime job(120)
  192.300 μs (273 allocations: 12.81 KiB)
62.386917015925626
```

Finally, let us just calculate it directly and we see that the actual computation time is here irrelevant - all the times observed above were the communication times.

```
@btime sum(rand() for _ in 1:120)
  164.559 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
61.00098819598033
```

We can see that the communication times for a single loop (equivalent of outer nested loop) were here 10x smaller than the inner nested loop.